# Dimensions do not match in linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying a simple linear regression model but don't understand why an error like this appears:

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, Y)
```

which produces following error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1518, 15]
```

The shapes of X and Y are:

```
X.shape, Y.shape
((1518, 1), (15, 1))
```

I am trying to predict these Y out of X but my dimensions are not the same; how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you share more details about your X and your Y?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'predict Y out of X' ?

Comment: my X and Y are a set of coordinates in 3D (x,y,z); i want to train a model by using X as input and want to predict the corresponding cluster centres which are located in Y; before reshaping them with .reshape(-1,1) they had the dimensions (506,3) and (5,3).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you split your features and explanatory variables wrong way.

Given on what you have written, you have `N=1518` samples and 15 features, one of which is the outcome variable.

If this is the case you input vector for Y and matrix for X should take the shapes:

```
X.shape = (1518,14)
Y.shape = (1518,1)
```

Assume you are given a `pd.dataframe`, with features names `F1...F15` and your dependent variable Y is `F3`, then you can split your variables as follows:

```
Y = df['F3']
X = df.drop('F3', axis=1)
```

Note: if you are currently using a numpy array, you an easily wrap this in a dataframe using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np_array)
```

Comment: I have to mention that my X had originally the shape (506, 3); meaning that I have 506 particles with (x,y,z) coordinates and I wanted to predict the corresponding cluster coordinates Y (x,y,z) the particles belong to. So my Y had the shape (5, 3)
and I reshaped them both with .reshape(-1,1) in order to feed in the model